# Extract a column vector from a sparse matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I am new to MATLAB.

I have a sparse matrix (`2649429x148`) which I got through `spconvert` function.
It is a sparse user-movie matrix. I want to get all the ratings for a particular movie. The user-id space has some gaps and is not continuous.

I tried the following

```
 mat     
            (967,1)                       1
           (7798,1)                       4
          (16272,1)                       2
          (21722,1)                       3
             .
             .
             .
          (11,148)                        5
          (2342432,148)                   5
          (2332332,148)                   5

 mat(:,4)      % it get the following 

            (967,1)                       1
           (7798,1)                       4
          (16272,1)                       2
          (21722,1)                       3
          (42773,1)                       3
          (48286,1)                       5
          (98649,1)                       2
         (156319,1)                       2
         (165720,1)                       2
          .........
```

I want to get `(xxxxxx, 4) .....`

How can I get a column vector of all the ratings for a particular movie?

Comment: This works fine for me: A = rand(2649429,148); a = A(:,4); what error do you get?

Comment: What's that magic number `4`? You need to be clear and specific about what procedures you have followed thus far, how is the data setup and what you intend to achieve.

Comment: @NKN But this isn't a sparse matrix.

Comment: @Divakar It is the fourth-column. Each column represents a movie in the full matrix.

Comment: @zeronone If each column represents a movie, where are the ratings?

Comment: so you are looking for **find** function. e.g. find(M(:,2)==4). but you should define the M function somehow that you can address that, either using a cell or multi-dimensional matrix structures.

Comment: @NKN I want to extract the fourth column into a column vector. Basically find(M(:,4)==<anything>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out if it works -

```
[~,col1,val] = find(mat);
ratings = val(col1==4)
```